# Plotting a CSV-file with time using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have currently started a project where I need to evaluate and plot data using python. The csv-file that I have to plot are structured like this:

> date,ch1,ch2,ch3,date2
> 11:56:20.149766,0.909257531,0.909420371,1.140183687, 13:56:20.149980
> 11:56:20.154008,0.895447016,0.895601869,1.122751355, 13:56:20.154197
> 11:56:20.157245,0.881764293,0.881911397,1.105638862, 13:56:20.157404
> 11:56:20.160590,-0.009178977,-0.000108901,-1.486875653, 13:56:20.160750
> 11:56:20.190473,-1.473576546,-1.477073431,-1.846657276, 13:56:20.190605
> 11:56:20.193810,-1.460405469,-1.463766813,-1.8300246, 13:56:20.193933
> 11:56:20.197139,-1.447362065,-1.450844049,-1.813711882, 13:56:20.197262
> 11:56:20.200480,-1.434574604,-1.437921286,-1.797878742, 13:56:20.200604
> 11:56:20.203803,-1.422042727,-1.425382376,-1.782045603, 13:56:20.203926
> 11:56:20.207136,-1.40951097,-1.412971258,-1.7663728, 13:56:20.207258
> 11:56:20.210472,-0.436505407,-0.438260257,-0.54675138, 13:56:20.210595
> 11:56:20.213804,0.953246772,0.953690529,1.19551909, 13:56:20.213921
> 11:56:20.217136,0.93815738,0.938464701,1.176487565, 13:56:20.217252
> 11:56:20.220472,0.923707485,0.924006522,1.158255577, 13:56:20.220590
> 11:56:20.223807,0.909385324,0.909676254,1.140343547, 13:56:20.223922
> 11:56:20.227132,0.895447016,0.895729899,1.122911215, 13:56:20.227248
> 11:56:20.230466,0.881892085,0.882039428,1.105798721, 13:56:20.230582

I can already read the file and print it using pandas:

```html
df = pd.read_csv (r'F:\Schule\HTL\Diplomarbeit\aw_python\datei_meas.csv')
print (df)
```

But now I want to plot the file using matplotlib. The first column date should be in the x axis and column 2,3 and 4 should be the y-values of different graphs.

I hope that anyone can help me with my problem.

Kind regards
Matthias

Edit:
This is what I have tried to convert the date-column into a readable file-format:

```html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mplcursors
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates




df = pd.read_csv (r'F:\Schule\HTL\Diplomarbeit\aw_python\datei_meas.csv')
print (df)
x_list = df.date
y = df.ch1
x = mdates.date2num(x_list)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show
```

And this is the occurring error message:

d = d.astype('datetime64[us]')

ValueError: Error parsing datetime string " 11:56:20.149766" at position 3

Comment: what have you tried, did you check the docs or other tutorials? Show your code and ask specific question.

Comment: Please include a [mre] of what you have done yet.